# MariaDB down on start replication

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication

tags: mariadb, mysql, database replication
I have upgraded the MariaDB server with a replicated database from 10.3.12 to 10.3.29. When I started replication I got an error:

```
2021-06-21 07:09:32 0x7f77400ab700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in file /home/buildbot/buildbot/padding_for_CPACK_RPM_BUILD_SOURCE_DIRS_PREFIX/mariadb-10.3.29/storage/innobase/row/row0ins.cc line 221
InnoDB: Failing assertion: !cursor->index->is_committed()
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to https://jira.mariadb.org/
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2021-06-21  7:09:32 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to find a record to delete-mark
210621  7:09:32 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
InnoDB: tuple This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

 0:We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.3.29-MariaDB-log
 SQL NULLkey_buffer_size=16777216
;read_buffer_size=2097152

max_used_connections=1
 1:max_threads=502
 len 4; hex thread_count=9
80It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 17505319 K  bytes of memory
42Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

fdThread pointer: 0x7f54b40012a8
2dAttempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
; asc  B -;;
```

SHOW SLAVE STATUS after restart of mysqld

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                Slave_IO_State: 
                   Master_Host: eggplant.***
                   Master_User: replication
                   Master_Port: 3306
                 Connect_Retry: 60
               Master_Log_File: eggplant-bin.031680
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 542851065
                Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000002
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 306
         Relay_Master_Log_File: eggplant-bin.031675
              Slave_IO_Running: No
             Slave_SQL_Running: No
               Replicate_Do_DB: 
           Replicate_Ignore_DB: ***
            Replicate_Do_Table: 
        Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                    Last_Errno: 0
                    Last_Error: 
                  Skip_Counter: 0
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 4
               Relay_Log_Space: 74965917
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File: 
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: No
            Master_SSL_CA_File: 
            Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
               Master_SSL_Cert: 
             Master_SSL_Cipher: 
                Master_SSL_Key: 
         Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                 Last_IO_Errno: 0
                 Last_IO_Error: 
                Last_SQL_Errno: 0
                Last_SQL_Error: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
              Master_Server_Id: 0
                Master_SSL_Crl: 
            Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
                    Using_Gtid: Slave_Pos
                   Gtid_IO_Pos: 
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids: 
                 Parallel_Mode: conservative
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State: 
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 0
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 0
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 0
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

SHOW MASTER STATUS (on replica)

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mango-bin.000002 |      328 |              |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

I tried to set GTID or binlog file and position. I tried to change master (version 10.3.12 or cascade over 10.3.29)

But when I set **log-slave-updates = 1** then replication starts without errors.

Comment: You said _"replicated database from 10.3.12 to 10.3.29"_ and the error message you posted is coming from 10.3.29. Between these two which one is the master and which one is the slave? And when you said _"When I start replication I have got error.."_, did you mean you start it using `START SLAVE` command after the MariaDB service being started or the error (or MariaDB crashed) when you start the service?

Comment: This is logs from replica. Version of replica is 10.3.29
Master: 10.3.12
Another master: 10.3.29.

I start service without start of replication because I have option **skip-slave-start**. When I start using START SLAVE I have got error and reboot of service.

Comment: So there are two masters(primary) for a single replica, correct? [Something like this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/multi-source-replication/)?

Comment: Basically one master (version 10.3.12) with scheme: `master (10.3.12)->slave (10.3.29)`

I just tried another one master with version 10.3.29 with scheme: `master (10.3.12)->New master (10.3.29)->Replica (10.3.29)`

Comment: So between ".. New master (10.3.29)->Replica (10.3.29)", which one crashed and which one you've set with `log-slave-updates = 1` that makes the replication successfully start?

Comment: Both of them crashed without `log-slave-updates = 1`

Comment: Can you please run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on both of the "New master (10.3.29)->Replica (10.3.29)" and [add the results into your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68062869/edit). You should be able to run it without starting the slave

Comment: I added `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` only from replica. Because new master downgraded to 10.3.12 already

Comment: Ok, so even the new master has been downgraded, the replication schema is still the same, right? Still `master -> new master -> replica`? Am I correct to assume that `master` will not be replicating to `replica` and `new master` is a `replica+master`? If that's the case then `new master` should be the only server that needed `log_slave_updates=1` [according to documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#log_slave_updates).

Comment: I suggest not to consider new master for simplicity. I have only master and replica. Replication on replica (version 10.3.29) falls without `log_slave_updates=1`

Comment: If like that, the replica should run without `log_slave_updates=1`. Can you confirm that the replica is not being set as master as well? You can run `SHOW MASTER STATUS` on the replica.

Comment: Yes. It will be only replica.

Comment: This might be related to MariaDB bug [MDEV-22373](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22373?focusedCommentId=191617&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-191617) who's work around is innodb_change_buffering=none. Or MDEV-14643 (same work around however a fresh logical reinialization may be required with a fixed version)

Comment: Do you have `log-bin` setting in your `my.ini`/`my.cnf` configuration file? If you do, remove (or comment) that setting and try turning on the replication without `log_slave_updates=1`.

Comment: With commented log-bin `START SLAVE` fails with any log_slave_updates

Comment: I'm out of ideas @DmitryRomanov. The only suggestion I have left is to reset the replication, new service and re-dump + re-import master data to the replica. Have you look at the bug info posted by @danblack?

Comment: I think it is very possible. Try to re-import data to the replica. I suppose I can't use mariabackup

Comment: I'm sure you know how to do it but let me know if you need any help. (-:

Answer (score 0):

Assertions in the MariaDB code are unexpected events by even the developers of the code. These should exist as [bug reports](https://jira.mariadb.org) for the developers to fix. Occasionally there may be a work around until a proper fix is implemented.

The likely case to this assertion is [MDEV-22373](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22373). This was fixed in 10.3.28 however prior to this is left a corruption in the secondary indexes of tables. I assume that you had a previous version to this as the replica before upgrading.

To correct this fault unfortunately the secondary indexes on the replica need to be dropped and recreated.

There is an orders of magnitude lower possibility that this is MariaDB specific regression that was fixed in MDEV-24449 which would require a complete logical dump and reload.

Comment: Can mysqlcheck show table with corrupted index?
Can I re-create index by command ALTER TABLE db.table ENGINE=InnoDB;? Or I need DROP/CREATE INDEX?

Comment: mysqlcheck isn't sufficient.  I think an alter table ENGINE=InnoDB should be sufficient.